# How to solve $x^2+y^2=z^2$ where $z^2$ is divisible by $73$?

Tags: number-theory

Solve $x^2+y^2=z^2$ and $z^2$ is  divisible by $73$, where  $x,y\in \Bbb N$, $x,y \in [1,72]$,  $z\in \Bbb R$ and $x<y$.

I know $z^2=73k$ and for $k=4n+1$ we have:

a) $k=5$

$x=2, y=19$ or $x=13, y=14$

b) $k=13$

$x=7, y=30$   or  $x=18, y=25$

c) I don't know next $k=??$ and $x=??$, $y=??$

Comment: Is $z$ integer?

Comment: Hint: if you can solve it for $z=73$ specifically, you can easily find solutions for any $z=73k$ from that.

Comment: @GregMartin $x^2+y^2=73^2$ has 48 , 55, but 5 , 11 is good solution too?

Comment: @piteer, something is wrong with your statement: $18^2+25^2=949$ which is not perfect square.It is better you pu  Z instead of $z^2$.

Comment: @piteer. $27^2+364^2=365^2$ and $365=5\times 73$, so this relation gives infinite x any by multiplying both side by a perfection square.

Comment: Sorry I forgot x,y∊[1,72]

Comment: Your proposed soultions are invalid, because if $z^2=73k$, then $k$ must be a multiple of $73$ (otherwise $z$ is not an integer).

Comment: Sorry I forgot z∊R

Comment: If $z \in \mathbb R$ and the *only* condition on $z$ is that $73|z^2$ why *use* $z^2$?  Why not simply say:  Solve for $x^2 + y^2 = 73M, M\in \mathbb N$?

Comment: Yes, but how to solve this?

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions.

Comment: @fleablood A good question, but one for the problem poser rather than the problem solver.

Comment: @EricSnyder I think this is a case of a poorly worded question misleading one into thinking what is involved in solving is quite different than what actually is required.  One thing to note we need $x^2 \equiv -y^2 \pmod{73}$ and ... there are only so many possibilities.  Trial and error (probably *not* the best way) won't take more than 20 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

An experimental approach:

$73=8^2+3^2$

$2^2\times 73=16^2+10^2$

$3^2\times 73=24^2+9^2$

$4^2\times 73=32^2+12^2$

$5^2\times 73=40^2+15^2$

$6^2\times 73=48^2+18^2$

$7^2\times 73=56^2+21^2$

The hidden value of k between $2^2$ and $3^2$ is$5$ and that between $3^2$ and $4^2$ is $13$. We have:

$13-5=8=2^3$

we guess the next difference is $2^4=16$ which is between $4^2$ and $5^2$ and next k is $13+16=29$ and we have:

$29\times 73=31^2+34^2$

We suppose our guess is correct for next k we check $29 +2^5=61$ and we have:

$61\times 73=22^2+63^2$

For $k=61+2^6=125$ we have:

$125\times 73=65^2+70^2$

In this way we may conclude that k values make a sequence like:

$k=1, 5, 13, 29, 61, 125,\cdot\cdot\cdot$

To find a formula for $k_n$ we can write:

$5=1+2^2$

$13=5+2^3$

$29=13+2^4$

$61=29+2^5$

$\cdot$

$\cdot$

$\cdot$

$k_n=k_{n-1}+2^{n+1}$

$----------------------$

Summing thses we get:

$K_n=1+2^2+2^3+2^4+ \ldots +2^{n+1}$

$k_n=1+2\big(\frac{2^{n+1}-2}{2-1}\big)=1+2^{n+2}-4$

Finally:

$k_n=2^{n+2}-3$

Comment: This misses quite a few valid values of $k$, including $17,37,41$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From the solution $(x,y)=(3,8)$ generate the rest as follows:

- *Generate multiples of $3^2+8^2$* -- Add $3$ to the first element and $8$ to the second.
- *Reduce the multiples modulo 73* -- Reduce the values of $x$ and $y$ generated from this addition modulo $73$.
- Identify this as the next solution.
- Iterate the above process until you arrive at $(0,0)$, which terminates the process.
- After generating the set of solutions above via the iteration scheme, reorder pairs as necessary to make the first element is less than the second. (For instance, you will get $(30,7)$ during the iteration process, which you leave in that form for the next iteration but then reorder as $(7,30)$ at the end.)

Note you will ultimately get $72$ solutions.

Comment: One thing I'm uncertain of here is what, exactly, should be reduced (mod $73$). The values of $(x,y)$? The values of $(x^2, y^2)$? The whole sum? I assume you mean $(x,y)$ since those are the values bounded by $[1,72]$, but it's unclear. Also, as $3,8,73$ are all coprime, this should generate $72$ solutions--is that the correct number of solutions?  Edit: looking closer it looks like you're talking about reducing $(x,y)$ since $(30,7)$ would immediately follow $(27,72)$.

Answer (score 0):

As you assessed, we want $x^2+y^2 =73k$ and $k=4n+1$. Or close to that. Specifically, by the sum of two squares theorem, $73k$ must lack any factors $p^m$, where $p = 3 \pmod 4$ and $k$ is odd. Hence your values of $k$ range through the integers which fit those bounds: $1,2,4,5,8,9,10,13,16,17,18,20,25,26,29$, and so on. We also know $k<2(72^2)/73 < 143$. (The last valid $k$ in that interval being $137$.) *EDIT*: Note that we might not catch every $k$ in the interval, and several values will have more than one solution.

Note that $21=3 \cdot 7$ is skipped due to the presence of forbidden factors, while $9 =3^2$ is not, thanks to the even power on $3$. But the main thing to pop out here is that not only are most integers $k=4n+1$ valid, so are most integers $k=2^a(4n+1)$. Also note that $n=0$ is valid, i.e., $k=2^a(1)$.

There's no particular algorithm for finding $(x,y)$ for a given valid $73k$, alas; however, @OscarLanzi's algorithm in their answer will be helpful. I'm not certain it'll hit every $(x,y)$ pair, but I have no proof either way. However, you now have a list to compare against. *EDIT*: After actually coding it, I'm certain Oscar's algorithm does, in fact, find all solutions: [Code and Solutions at SageCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNzsEKwyAMBuC74DvkMlAMrrOHlsGeYQ9QWrBsAylYcRbUp58iG8stX36SaFwxYoIb9Dhihx0llNyP4I5QbJpr-9o9GDAWpouUg5qvlECpWAIsCs3hBEPfrC5iSaz_lovFRYGAtKhGW6EM51-kHZTauad9sI03dd7YwMp3mLHa9zH53n1gvEaAkpZqE_4BBB0x-g==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Comment: The method does capture all solutions. The claim is based on $4n+1$ prime moduli having only one pair of square roots of $-1$. You may want to see what happens with a smaller prime such as $13$ in place of $73$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Yeah, once I saw what the algorithm did it rapidly became clear that it would produce all the solutions. I wish I could mark your answer as "best" but that's up to OP.

Answer (score -1):

$x^2+y^2=z^2$ and $1\le x,y\le72$, so that $z^2 \le 2\times 72^2$, since $73|z$, z must be 73.
Since you have got $73=3^2+8^2$, so $73 = (3+8i)(3-8i)$, $73^2= (3+8i)^2 (3-8i)^2=(-55+48i)(-55-48i)$, so we have $73^2=55^2+48^2$

Comment: Note that $z$ need not be an integer, and there are many values of $z^2$ greater than $73$ which fit the conditions.